# How to send excel file directly to printer or print html code?

Tags: asp.net, excel, printing

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 (C#) site that loads an excel file and then I want to print on a label printer at teh user's default printer?

1. Excel File is populated on sheet1
2. Print Area has been set in the file
3. When I print from excel to the label printer it prints fine.

I would like to send the excel file to the user's default printer. and have it automatically print the print area or the first sheet.

I would be open to sending a HTML String that has my data formatted in a table if that is possible.  That would eliminate any need for the excel file.

Microsoft Excel is not installed on the webserver so using the Excel Refrence is out.  But I do have the Microsoft Office SDK 2.0 and can use that if needed.

Thanks in advance for any tips or any directions.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you could do manually, you can record using the macro recorder and figure out the code. Here is a generated code for sending files to my printer:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "HP LaserJet P2014 on Ne03:"
ExecuteExcel4Macro "PRINT(1,,,1,,,,,,,,2,""HP LaserJet P2014 on Ne03:"",,TRUE,,FALSE)"
```

You could change the variables to match your own printer